# Laravel Query builder query equivalent to SQL query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

My query is working fine only problem in this where clause. Please tell me what will query builder query in Laravel, equivalent to this query

```
WHERE (interest_request.sender_id = 6 or interest_request.to_user_id = 6) 
AND interest_request.interest_status =2 
and profiles.profile_id not in (6)
```

I am using following query builder but not working

```
where('to_user_id',$my_profile_id)->orwhere
('sender_id',$my_profile_id)->where('interest_status','2')
->whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', $my_profile_id)
```

Comment: instead posting only part post whole query please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you'll have to use a nested `where` clause:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($my_profile_id) {
    $query->where('to_user_id', $my_profile_id)
        ->orWhere('sender_id', $my_profile_id);
})
->where('interest_status', 2)
->where('profile_id', '!=', $my_profile_id)
```

Also you don't need to use a `whereIn` (or `whereNotIn`) query if you have only one id in the list.

Answer (score 0):

i would assume it will be the following in sql:

```
WHERE to_user_id = $my_profile_id  
OR sender_id = $my_profile_id
AND interest_status = 2
AND profiles.profile_id NOT IN ($my_profile_id)
```

When i use orwhere() statements i use callback functions:

```
where(function($query) {$query->something})
->orwhere(function($query) {$query->otherOptions})
```